# Dynamic DropDownList Using Laravel 5.1 error class'City' not found

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am new in laravel so pls help from dynamic dropdown list.....this project is created in laravel 5.1.

`index.blade.php`

```
    <div class="cls2">
        <ul>
            <li><label for="state"class="lbl">State</label></li>
            <li>:</li>
            <li><select  name="state" id="state" class="txtb">
                    <option>Select State</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($State as $state) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $state['state_id'] ?>"><?=$state['state_name'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                    </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cls2">
        <ul>
            <li><label for="city"class="lbl">City</label></li>
            <li>:</li>
            <li><select  name="city" id="city" class="txtb">
                    <option>Select CIty</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($City as $city) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $city['city_id'] ?>"><?= $city['city_name'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                </select>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="sub">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnsub"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('/subdropdown',function()
   $state_id = Input::get('subcat_id');  
  $city = City::where('state_id','=',$state_id)->get();
 return Response::json($city);
 });

Route::get('/','Employee@index'); //route for index.blade
```

Controller Employee.php

```
public function index()
{
    $state=State::all();
    return view('employee.index')->with('State',$state);
}
```

Model City.php

```
class City extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'city';
  protected $fillable = ['city_name','state_id'];

 public function State()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('State');
 }
}
```

Model State.php

```
class State extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'state';

  protected $fillable = ['state_name'];

public function City()
{
   return $this->hasMany('City');
}
}
```

The Error like show like Class 'City' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registration\app\Http\routes.php on line 36

Comment: You need to think about your namespaces - at a guess your routes.php file is namespaced to `\App\Http` (or `\App\Providers`, as it's included in `\App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`), whereas your City model is likely in `\App` or `\App\Models`.

Comment: Thanks....i wrote use `App\Model\City;` its working....Thank u alexrussell

Comment: No problem - you should write up the details what you did as an answer and accept it when the system allows you to, so as to help people finding this question in the future.

Comment: ya...ofcurse .nice to meeting u..